# Class 'Zend_Controller_Action' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to make work a project locally. I got it by svn and i never worked on it previously.

i have this error while trying to fire the indexController:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Controller_Action' not found
```

All the librairies seem to be in my project. Does anyone know where this come from ?

thanks in advance

My bootstrap it it helps:

```
<?php
/**
 * Init application directory
 */
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../applications/' . APPLICATION_NAME . '/'));
defined('PROJECT_PATH')
    || define('PROJECT_PATH', realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'));
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'development'));


/**
 * Init error
 */
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/**
 * Set libraries include path
 */
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'services',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'inline',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extension' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Sortable' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib',
    PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sfYaml',
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models',
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'amf',
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'controllers',
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'doctrine',
    APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'models' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'data',
    get_include_path(),
)));

/**
 * Zend application
 */
require_once 'Zend' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Loader' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

/**
 * Config
 */
global $config;
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'configs' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');

/**
 * Doctrine
 */
$dsn="mysql:dbname=" . $config->resources->db->dbname . ";host=" . $config->resources->db->host;
Doctrine::setExtensionsPath(PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extension');
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
$manager->registerExtension('Sortable',PROJECT_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'library' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'extension' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Sortable' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'lib' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Doctrine' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Template');
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $config->resources->db->username, $config->resources->db->password);
$conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dbh,'portail');
$conn->setOption('username', $config->resources->db->username);
$conn->setOption('password', $config->resources->db->password);
$conn->setCharset("utf8");
$conn->setCollate('utf8_general_ci');
$conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);

$layout = new Zend_Layout();
$layout->setLayoutPath('/layouts/scripts/');

/**
 * Router
 */
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();
```

Comment: could you confirm if there's a file at `library/Zend/Controller/Action.php`?

Comment: Okay. When you say 'trying to fire the indexController' what do you mean? Viewing the site homepage?

Comment: yes, that's i am trying to do...

Comment: i tried to add this in the top of my IndexController : "require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php' and i have the following error: Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Controller/Action.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you included in your comment shows the include_path of `.;C:\php\pear`, which does not include your application's 'library' folder, or any of the other paths that are added in the bootstrap you included in your question. So either this bootstrap is not being run, or it's being overridden elsewhere in your application.